# Deriving basic form of sine wave

Tags: wave-equation

I'm trying to derive the basic form of a sine wave:

$$y = A \cdot \sin(\omega t + \theta)$$

I'm guessing I could probably first derive the cosine wave as follows and then add a phase of $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

$$y = Re(z) = Re(A \cdot \cos(\omega t) + i\cdot \sin(\omega t)) = A \cdot \cos(\omega t)$$

Is this derivation the most common method and if it isn't what are other ways could I use to derive the basic form of a sine wave? Any other info regarding this basic form would be greatly appreciated as well?

Comment: What does it mean to "derive the form of a sine wave"? In particular, derive from _what_?

Comment: $\sin()$ and $\cos()$ are equally fundamental.  There's no advantage in deriving $\sin()$ from $\cos()$ over $\cos()$ from $\sin()$, unless you just have an assignment where you are told to do that.  If you understand the relationship between them, you're already there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

simply you have:

$$
y=A\sin(\omega t +\theta)=A\cos (\omega t +\theta -\dfrac{\pi}{2})
$$

So the two forms represents the same function an can be derived the one by the other simply by a change of $\theta$.